# M1: crash with simulator iOS 13 or older and Xcode 12.3 on mac with M1 chip and Big Sur

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arm64, apple-m1

I've got this strange issue:

- Xcode 12.3
- macOs 11.1 Big Sur
- iOS Simulator < 14

I added the suggested "excluded architectures" **arm64** to let my project works on simulators iOS 14

but if i use older iOS on simulator it seems to works, no warnings or errors in compilation phase

it all seems to works, but if i run some line of code that are ok (they worked in previous mac and they still do on iOS 14 simulator) it simply crash

for instance:

```
NSData *encodedString = [@"a" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSAttributedString *htmlString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:encodedString options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

the code is correct, nothing is wrong in it, no warning or else
i noticed similar crashes for other methods

anyone had similar crash? anyone solved?

P.S. if i remove "exclude" arm64 i cannot run on iOS 14, but still have crash on iOS 13, anyway

Comment: AFAIK simulators for iOS <14 are generally problematic on M1 macs right now and we can only hope that these bugs will be ironed out soon.

Comment: I also have this issue. Initializing a WKWebView causes crash on M1 mac iOS 13 simulator.

Comment: Despite encouraging other developers to update their code for the M1 MacBook, it feels like Apple have not updated Xcode to deal with iOS 12 and 13 simulators.

Comment: May I know, has this issue being sorted out, or M1 user will still face this problem? Thanks.

Comment: still no fix for this bug, ios 13 simulator has still crashes for correct code